# Github action job recurse the directory structure as the working-directory?

Tags: vagrant, github-actions, vagrantfile

I have the following directory structure, and one github action. I want to run the github aciton in every sub folder like (centos7, centos8, ubuntu2004 ...).

How to config the github action?

```
.
├── centos7
│   └── Vagrantfile
├── centos8
│   └── Vagrantfile
├── ubuntu2004
    └── Vagrantfile
```

```yaml
name: vagrant-up

on: [push]

jobs:
    vagrant-up:
        runs-on: macos-10.15 
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: Run vagrant up
              run: |
                    vagrant up

            - name: package box
              run: | 
                    vagrant package --base vagrant-default --output default.box
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix. Please find below code which should work for you.

```
name: vagrant-up

on: [push]

jobs:
    vagrant-up:
        runs-on: macos-10.15 
        strategy:
           matrix:
             Directory: [centos7, centos8, centos9]
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2

            - name: Run vagrant up
              working-directory: ${{ matrix.Directory }}
              run: |
                    vagrant up

            - name: package box
              working-directory: ${{ matrix.Directory }}
              run: | 
                    vagrant package --base vagrant-default --output default.box
```